# Derivative of integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

Given $f$ is function with continous derivatives, how do I obtain $f(x)$ in terms of $x$ from the equation below? Thanks in advance.

$$
f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{2t} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} s f'(s) ds
$$

Comment: Note that for a continuous function $g$ we have $g(p)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{p-t}^{p+t}g(s)\,ds$.

Comment: @DiegoMath I know fundamental theorem of Integral calculus . Can you elaborate please .thanks

Comment: i don't think the problem as posed has a solution.here is why.  if $\ f$ is a solution so is any multiple of $f,$ for example $2f.$ what you need is set another condition such as the value $f$ at another $x$ value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to rewrite the equation as $f(x)=xf'(x)$. If you let $F(x)=\int_0^xsf'(s)ds$, then 
$$
\frac1{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)\,ds=\frac1{2t}\left[\int_0^{x+t}sf'(s)\,ds-\int_0^{x-t}sf'(s)\,ds\right]=\frac{F(x+t)-F(x-t)}{2t}\\
=\frac12\,\left[\frac{F(x+t)-F(x)}t+\frac{F(x)-F(x-t)}t\right]\\
\to F'(x)=xf'(x).
$$

This shows that you cannot determine $f(3)$, as it could be any value. Because, for any number $c$, $f(x)=cx$ satisfies your equation.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) = cx$

Comment: can you xplain how tu use FTOC in this case ? thanks

Comment: simon is right. what is on rhs of op is the average value of $x\frac{df}{dx}$ over a shrinking interval centered at $x.$ so equation now reads $f = x\frac{df}{dx}.$ general solution is $f = cx.$

Comment: @Martin Tons of thanks Martin . This is what i needed . Thank you so much

Comment: @Simon: you are right, thanks.

Comment: @MartinArgerami How have you written ( F(x) - F(x-t) )/ t  = F'(t) ..in transition from second last step to last step

Comment: Not "equal" but "tends to". You have $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac {F (x)-F (x-t)} t=\lim_{t\to0}\frac {F (x-t)-F (x)}{- t}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac {F (x+h)-F (x)} h=F'(x). $$

Comment: @MartinArgerami is their a shortcut to these types of questions

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus gives $f(x) = x f'(x)$ or ${f'(x) \over f(x)} = {1 \over x}$. Hence $\ln { f(x) \over f(1)} = \ln x$, or $f(x) = f(1) x$.